# Is there a dplyr equivalent to data.table::rleid?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, run-length-encoding

`data.table` offers a nice convenience function, [`rleid`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.4/topics/rleid) for run-length encoding:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(grp=rep(c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B"), c(2, 2, 3, 1, 2)), value=1:10)
rleid(DT$grp)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5
```

I can mimic this in base `R` with:

```
df <- data.frame(DT)
rep(seq_along(rle(df$grp)$values), times = rle(df$grp)$lengths)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5
```

Does anyone know of a `dplyr` equivalent (?) or is the "best" way to create the `rleid` behavior with `dplyr` is to do something like the following

```
library(dplyr)

my_rleid = rep(seq_along(rle(df$grp)$values), times = rle(df$grp)$lengths)

df %>%
  mutate(rleid = my_rleid)
```

Comment: Dplyr is compatible with data.table. If, for some reason, you don't want to load data.table, I think your base solution is good. You could try filing a feature request with dplyr, but I'd say the odds of a good reception are no better than 50/50.

Comment: `cumsum(c(1L, df$grp[-nrow(df)] != df$grp[-1]))` also for base

Comment: Consider changing the accepted answer to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74428002/680068 - dplyr now has dedicated function: consecutive_id

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From `v1.1.0` [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) added the function `consecutive_id()` modeled after `data.table::rleid()` with the same support for multiple vectors and the treatment of `NA` values.

```
 library(dplyr)
 
 DT %>%
   mutate(id = consecutive_id(grp)) 

    grp value id
 1:   A     1  1
 2:   A     2  1
 3:   B     3  2
 4:   B     4  2
 5:   C     5  3
 6:   C     6  3
 7:   C     7  3
 8:   A     8  4
 9:   B     9  5
10:   B    10  5
```

Comment: Just checked available with dplyr_1.1.0.

Answer (score 31):

You can just do (when you have both [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) and [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) loaded):

```
DT <- DT %>% mutate(rlid = rleid(grp))
```

this gives:

> ```
> > DT
>     grp value rlid
>  1:   A     1    1
>  2:   A     2    1
>  3:   B     3    2
>  4:   B     4    2
>  5:   C     5    3
>  6:   C     6    3
>  7:   C     7    3
>  8:   A     8    4
>  9:   B     9    5
> 10:   B    10    5
> ```

When you don't want to load [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) separately you can also use (as mentioned by @DavidArenburg in the comments):

```
DT <- DT %>% mutate(rlid = data.table::rleid(grp))
```

And as @RichardScriven said in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507868/is-there-a-dplyr-equivalent-to-data-tablerleid/33508069#comment54799813_33508069) you can just copy/steal it:

```
myrleid <- data.table::rleid
```

Comment: Agreed, but I'm looking to avoid the call to `data.table::rleid` if possible.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Why? If I may ask?

Comment: To stay entirely in `dplyr`, `tidyr`, hadley-verse land.

Comment: Steal it ... `myrleid <- data.table::rleid`

Comment: @RichardScriven that's likely what I'll resort to, but seeing if anyone else has other ideas. Another reason is stay in one "paradigm" for teaching/education purposes and avoid introducing too many packages to new users.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns If your are only going to use the hadley-verse, then you will limit yourself very much imo.

Comment: Not trying to start any debates/wars, I think I'll accept @Jaap before this gets out of hand...

Comment: This works like a champ with shift() also, for which there's not a dplyr equivalent without a bunch of ugly code.

Comment: @TheProletariat True, but it would look very similar to Alex's answer.

Answer (score 26):

If you want to use just base R and **dplyr**, the better way is to wrap up your own one or two line version of `rleid()` as a function and then apply that whenever you need it.

```
library(dplyr)

myrleid <- function(x) {
    x <- rle(x)$lengths
    rep(seq_along(x), times=x)
}

## Try it out
DT <- DT %>% mutate(rlid = myrleid(grp))
DT
#   grp value rlid
# 1:   A     1    1
# 2:   A     2    1
# 3:   B     3    2
# 4:   B     4    2
# 5:   C     5    3
# 6:   C     6    3
# 7:   C     7    3
# 8:   A     8    4
# 9:   B     9    5
#10:   B    10    5
```

Comment: Small note: `rleid()` is designed to work with lists/data.frames/data.tables as well, e.g., `rleid(c(1,1,1,2,2,2), c(3,4,4,5,5,6))`. Nothing special about implementing it, but just to note the difference.

Comment: @Arun Should `data.table::rleid(mtcars)` work? (It doesn't, for me, though its help file would lead me believe  that it should...)

Comment: Yes, but it's `rleidv(mtcars)` (the SE version). `rleid()` takes `...` as input -- so we'll have to provide each column separately.. (for interactive cases).

Comment: watch out: in case of `NA` this solution does not provide the same solution of `data.table::rleid`. Check out `x <- c(1,1,1,NA,NA,2,2); myrleid(x); data.table::rleid(x)`. `rle` consider each `NA` as part of its own group.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it using the `lag` function from `dplyr`.

```
DT <-
    DT %>%
    mutate(rleid = (grp != lag(grp, 1, default = "asdf"))) %>%
    mutate(rleid = cumsum(rleid))
```

gives

```
> DT
    grp value rleid
 1:   A     1     1
 2:   A     2     1
 3:   B     3     2
 4:   B     4     2
 5:   C     5     3
 6:   C     6     3
 7:   C     7     3
 8:   A     8     4
 9:   B     9     5
10:   B    10     5
```

Answer (score 10):

A simplification (involving no additional package) of the approach used by the OP could be:

```
DT %>%
 mutate(rleid = with(rle(grp), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)))

   grp value rleid
1    A     1     1
2    A     2     1
3    B     3     2
4    B     4     2
5    C     5     3
6    C     6     3
7    C     7     3
8    A     8     4
9    B     9     5
10   B    10     5
```

Or:

```
DT %>%
 mutate(rleid = rep(seq(ls <- rle(grp)$lengths), ls))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of very good solutions here, but I would like to note that some do not give the same result as `data.table::rleid()` when the data has `NAs`. Keep in mind that `data.table::rleid()` increments everytime there is a change, including `NAs`.

**Data:**

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# Data
DT2 = data.table(grp=rep(c("A", "B", NA, "C", "A", NA, "B", NA), c(2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1)), value=1:14)
df <- data.frame(DT2)

# data.table reild
DT2[, rleid := rleid(DT2$grp)]
DT2
#>      grp value rleid
#>  1:    A     1     1
#>  2:    A     2     1
#>  3:    B     3     2
#>  4:    B     4     2
#>  5: <NA>     5     3
#>  6: <NA>     6     3
#>  7:    C     7     4
#>  8:    C     8     4
#>  9:    C     9     4
#> 10:    A    10     5
#> 11: <NA>    11     6
#> 12:    B    12     7
#> 13:    B    13     7
#> 14: <NA>    14     8
```

Just for example, Alex's solution is perfect for OP but doesn't give same result as `data.table::rleid()` when dealing with `NAs`:

```r
# Alex's solution
df %>% 
  mutate(rleid = (grp != lag(grp, 1, default = "asdf"))) %>%
  mutate(rleid = cumsum(rleid))
#>     grp value rleid
#> 1     A     1     1
#> 2     A     2     1
#> 3     B     3     2
#> 4     B     4     2
#> 5  <NA>     5    NA
#> 6  <NA>     6    NA
#> 7     C     7    NA
#> 8     C     8    NA
#> 9     C     9    NA
#> 10    A    10    NA
#> 11 <NA>    11    NA
#> 12    B    12    NA
#> 13    B    13    NA
#> 14 <NA>    14    NA
```

Here is an easy to read and understand `tidyverse` (although slower) equivalent to `data.table::rleid()`:

```r
# like rleid()
df %>% 
  mutate(
    rleid = cumsum(
      ifelse(is.na(grp), "DEFAULT", grp) != lag(ifelse(is.na(grp), "DEFAULT", grp), default = "DEFAULT")
    )
  )
#>     grp value rleid
#> 1     A     1     1
#> 2     A     2     1
#> 3     B     3     2
#> 4     B     4     2
#> 5  <NA>     5     3
#> 6  <NA>     6     3
#> 7     C     7     4
#> 8     C     8     4
#> 9     C     9     4
#> 10    A    10     5
#> 11 <NA>    11     6
#> 12    B    12     7
#> 13    B    13     7
#> 14 <NA>    14     8
```

Here is an easy to read and understand `tidyverse` equivalent to `data.table::rleid()` but that ignores `NAs`:

```r
# like rleid() but ignoring NAs
df %>% 
 mutate(
    rleid = cumsum(
      (!is.na(grp)) & (grp != lag(ifelse(is.na(grp), "DEFAULT", grp), default = "DEFAULT"))
    )
 )
#>     grp value rleid
#> 1     A     1     1
#> 2     A     2     1
#> 3     B     3     2
#> 4     B     4     2
#> 5  <NA>     5     2
#> 6  <NA>     6     2
#> 7     C     7     3
#> 8     C     8     3
#> 9     C     9     3
#> 10    A    10     4
#> 11 <NA>    11     4
#> 12    B    12     5
#> 13    B    13     5
#> 14 <NA>    14     5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>