# Extracting alternating sequence from vector in R

Tags: r, vector, sequence

I have a data looking like the following:

```
A= c(0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,-1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,-1)
```

The goal is to extract alternating -1s and 1s. I want to make a function where the input vector contains 0,1, and -1. The output ideally spits out all the 0s and alternating -1s and 1s.

For instance, the desired output for the above example is:

```
 B= c(0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1)
```

The two 1s in the 9th and 10th location in A is turned to 0 because we only keep the first 1 or -1 appearing. The -1s in 16th and 17th location of A is turned to 0 for this reason as well.

Anyone have a good idea for making such a function?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted and vtc? It is well explained with an example.

Comment: The odd value it seems to me is position 16. It switches from `0` at position 15 to `-1` but is removed. Why?

Comment: The goal is to only keep unique 1s and -1s to oscillate. There is -1 in the 13th location, so until next 1 is observed, all -1s are turned in to 0s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Identify positions of nonzero values:

```
w = which(A != 0)
```

For each run of similar values, in `A[w]`, take the position of the first:

```
library(data.table)
wkeep = tapply(w, rleid(A[w]), FUN = function(x) x[1])
```

Set all other values to zero:

```
# following @alexis_laz's approach
B = numeric(length(A)) 
B[ wkeep ] = A[ wkeep ]
```

This way, you don't have to make comparisons in a loop, which R is slow at, I think.

---

`rleid` comes from data.table. With base R, you can make `wkeep` with @alexis_laz's suggestion:

```
wkeep = w[c(TRUE, A[w][-1L] != A[w][-length(w)])]
```

Or write your own `rleid`, as in [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509966/1191259).

Comment: On a same approach: `w = which(A != 0L); wkeep = w[c(TRUE, A[w][-1L] != A[w][-length(w)])]; ans = numeric(length(A)); ans[wkeep] = A[wkeep]; ans`

Comment: @alexis_laz the existing answer is excellent. But I'd say yours is different enough to be posted on its own, especially as it uses base R functions only (I found it easier to understand).

Comment: Thanks @alexis_laz . I've added your approach for `wkeep` and overwritten my third step with yours (for making `ans`).

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have a very big data and this is very helpful.

Comment: @jay2020 note you are able to change your accepted answer if after you accept the first answer a new answer appears that you prefer. (I usu. wait a few hours at least before accepting anything)

Answer (score 3):

This is really just a Reification of GWarius's pseudo-code. (I already had a structure but logic that was failing.)

```
last1 <- -A[which(A != 0)[1] ] # The opposite of the first non-zero item
for (i in seq_along(A) ){ 
          if( last1==1 &&  A[i]==-1  ){ last1 <- -1
          } else {if (last1 == -1 && A[i] == 1) { last1 <- 1
                 } else {A[i] <- 0}} }
 A
 [1]  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  0
[24]  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1

> identical(A, B)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Yeah. I tried with last1=0 and that failed. I guess you could set it to be `-A[which(A != 0)[1] ]`

Comment: Thank you. I already solved it using Warlus's suggestion so I had to choose Warlus. But I really appreciate your time.

Comment: No problem. I've spent more time on some questions and gotten fewer upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

you have to slide all the array and with a flag variable you check if previously you found 1 or -1.
it could be possible pseudo-code algorithm:

```
while i < length(a):

   if flag == 1 && a[i]=-1:
      b[i]=a[i];
      flag = -1;
   else if flag == -1 && a[i] = 1:
      b[i]=a[i];
      flag = 1;
   else:
      b[i]=0;
   i++;
}//end of while
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice