# Is there a function in dplyr corresponding to the function `shift` in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

In the `data.table` package, there is a `shift` function which helps process data in consecutive rows. Like this:

```
> shift(1:10, 1:3, type = "lag")
[[1]]
 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

[[2]]
 [1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8

[[3]]
 [1] NA NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

And I know that in `dplyr` package, there are functions like `lead` and `lag` which do about the same thing as `shift` in the `data.table` package. But the problem is that you can not really specify consecutive rows but only check two rows at the same time. For example:

```
> lag(1:10, 1)
 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
> lag(1:10, 2)
 [1] NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
> lag(1:10, 3)
 [1] NA NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

But you cannot do something like `lag(1:10, 1:3)` which gives errors as

```
lag(1:10, 1:3)
```

> Error in lag(1:10, 1:3) : n must be a single positive integer
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (n == 0) return(x) :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

So my question is that if there is a function in `dplyr` that corresponds to the function `shift` in `data.table`. Any clarification will be appreciated!

Comment: I think you're stuck with `lapply(1:3, function(i) dplyr::lag(1:10, i))`

Comment: You could follow the advice in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33507868/

Comment: Thanks! I just figured that I can steal the function `shift` from `data.table`.

Comment: Stealing it with `shift <- data.table::shift` shouldn't be an issue, as data.table doesn't have any dependencies since 1.9.7 and it builds very fast. So it won't slow or bloat environment setup. BTW. feel free to self answer your question.