# Create counter with multiple variables that restart within each subgroup

Tags: r, counter, multivalue

I have a dataframe with two columns (ident and value). I would like to create a counter that restart every time ident value change and also when value within each ident change. Here is an example to make it clear.

```
# ident value counter
#-------------------- 
#  1     0       1
#  1     0       2
#  1     1       1
#  1     1       2
#  1     1       3
#  1     0       1
#  1     1       1
#  1     1       2
#  2     1       1
#  2     0       1
#  2     0       2
#  2     0       3
```

I've tried the plyr package

```
ddply(mydf, .(ident, value), transform, .id = seq_along(ident))
```

Same result with the data.frame package.

Comment: This will not handle the duplication of (1,1) group on the 7th row. It will be counted as 4,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` the two values together and use `length` attribute of `rle` to get the length of consecutive numbers. We then use `sequence` to generate the counter.

```
df$counter <- sequence(rle(paste0(df$dent, df$value))$lengths)
df
#   dent value counter
#1     1     0       1
#2     1     0       2
#3     1     1       1
#4     1     1       2
#5     1     1       3
#6     1     0       1
#7     1     1       1
#8     1     1       2
#9     2     1       1
#10    2     0       1
#11    2     0       2
#12    2     0       3
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` alternative with the use of the `rleid`/`rowid` functions. With `rleid` you create a *run length id* for consecutive values, which can be used as a group. `1:.N` or `rowid` can be used to create the counter. The code:

```
library(data.table)
# option 1:
setDT(d)[, counter := 1:.N, by = .(ident,rleid(value))]
# option 2:
setDT(d)[, counter := rowid(ident, rleid(value))]
```

which both give:

```
> d
    ident value counter
 1:     1     0       1
 2:     1     0       2
 3:     1     1       1
 4:     1     1       2
 5:     1     1       3
 6:     1     0       1
 7:     1     1       1
 8:     1     1       2
 9:     2     1       1
10:     2     0       1
11:     2     0       2
12:     2     0       3
```

---

With `dplyr` it is a bit less straightforward:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(ident, val.gr = cumsum(value != lag(value, default = first(value)))) %>% 
  mutate(counter = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-val.gr)
```

As an alternative to the `cumsum`-function you could [also use `rleid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33508069/2204410) from `data.table`.

---

Used data:

```
d <- structure(list(ident = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
                    value = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), 
               .Names = c("ident", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```