# Subset rows for each group based on a character in a column and order of occurrence in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a data similar to this.

```
B <- data.frame(State = c(rep("Arizona", 8), rep("California", 8), rep("Texas", 8)), 
  Account = rep(c("Balance", "Balance", "In the Bimester", "In the Bimester", "Expenses",  
  "Expenses", "In the Bimester", "In the Bimester"), 3), Value = runif(24))
```

You can see that `Account` has 4 occurrences of the element `"In the Bimester"`, **two "chunks"** of two elements for each state, `"Expenses"` in between them.

The order here matters because the first chunk is not referring to the same thing as the second chunk.

My data is actually more complex, It has a 4th variable, indicating what each row of `Account` means. The number of its elements for each `Account` element (factor per se) can change. For example, In some state, the first "chunk" of `"In the Bimester"` can have 6 rows and the second, 7; but, I cannot differentiate by this 4th variable.

**Desired:** I'd like to subset my data, spliting those two `"In the Bimester"` by each state, subsetting only the rows of the first "chunks" by each state or the second "chunks".

I have a solution using `data.table` package, but I'm finding it kind of poor. any thoughts?

```
library(data.table)
B <- as.data.table(B)
B <- B[, .(Account, Value, index = 1:.N), by = .(State)]
x <- B[Account == "Expenses", .(min_ind = min(index)), by = .(State)]
B <- merge(B, x, by = "State")
B <- B[index < min_ind & Account == "In the Bimester", .(Value), by = .(State)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
B %>% mutate(helper = data.table::rleid(Account)) %>% 
      filter(Account == "In the Bimester") %>% 
      group_by(State) %>% filter(helper == min(helper)) %>% select(-helper)

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   State [3]
#        State         Account      Value
#       <fctr>          <fctr>      <dbl>
# 1    Arizona In the Bimester 0.17730148
# 2    Arizona In the Bimester 0.05695585
# 3 California In the Bimester 0.29089678
# 4 California In the Bimester 0.86952723
# 5      Texas In the Bimester 0.54076144
# 6      Texas In the Bimester 0.59168138
```

If instead of `min` you use `max` you'll get the last occurrences of `"In the Bimester"` for each `State`. You can also exclude `Account` column by changing the last pipe to `select(-helper,-Account)`.

**p.s.** If you don't want to use `rleid` from `data.table` and just use `dplyr` functions take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507868/is-there-a-dplyr-equivalent-to-data-tablerleid).