# Increase by one for each change in group in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to change this

```
data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2), val=c('a','a','b','a','a','a','b'))
  id val
1  1   a
2  1   a
3  1   b
4  1   a
5  1   a
6  2   a
7  2   b
```

into

```
  id val
1  1   1
2  1   1
3  1   2
4  1   3
5  1   3
6  2   1
7  2   2
```

For each `id`, the value of `val` begins with 1 and increases by 1 when `val` changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(val = with(rle(as.numeric(val)), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)))

     id   val
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     1
2     1     1
3     1     2
4     1     3
5     1     3
6     2     1
7     2     2
```

The same idea using `rleid()` from `data.table`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(val = rleid(val))
```

Comment: For folks who don't want to load data.table alongside dplyr (eg because of namespace conflicts): https://stackoverflow.com/q/33507868

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` we can `group_by` `id` and increment the counter every time the next value changes from the current one.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(val = cumsum(val != lag(val, default = TRUE)))

#     id   val
#   <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1
#2     1     1
#3     1     2
#4     1     3
#5     1     3
#6     2     1
#7     2     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

```
f <- as.integer(as.factor(df1$val))
1 + ave(f, df1$id, FUN = function(x) cumsum(c(0, diff(x) != 0)))
#[1] 1 1 2 3 3 1 2
```

Then assign the result to `df1$val`.

Answer (score 2):

`data.table`'s `rleid()` is made for this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(xy)
xy[, rleid(val), id]

   id V1
1:  1  1
2:  1  1
3:  1  2
4:  1  3
5:  1  3
6:  2  1
7:  2  2
```