# Assign multiple start and stop dates for single variable in group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset, where I have different `provider` attending a `site` multiple times.

I want to create columns to show `start` and `stop` dates where they are present.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
x <- tibble(
  "site" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
  "provider" = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "A"),
  "date" = seq(from = as.Date("2019-01-01"), to = as.Date("2019-01-10"), by = 'day'),
)
```

I've been unable to create a bit of code that adequately captures the fact that a provider might be present several times. The best I got so far is:

```
x %>%
  group_by(site, provider) %>%
  mutate("start" = min(date),
         "end" = max(date))
```

Which creates this:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   site, provider [5]
    site provider date       start      end       
   <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1     1 A        2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-05
 2     1 B        2019-01-02 2019-01-02 2019-01-02
 3     1 C        2019-01-03 2019-01-03 2019-01-03
 4     1 A        2019-01-04 2019-01-01 2019-01-05
 5     1 A        2019-01-05 2019-01-01 2019-01-05
 6     2 C        2019-01-06 2019-01-06 2019-01-09
 7     2 C        2019-01-07 2019-01-06 2019-01-09
 8     2 A        2019-01-08 2019-01-08 2019-01-10
 9     2 C        2019-01-09 2019-01-06 2019-01-09
10     2 A        2019-01-10 2019-01-08 2019-01-10
```

However, this only process the individual `provider` once per `site`.

Here is what I would like the final dataset to look like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   site, provider [5]
    site provider date       start      end       
   <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1     1 A        2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01  # A stops at 2019-01-01
 2     1 B        2019-01-02 2019-01-02 2019-01-02
 3     1 C        2019-01-03 2019-01-03 2019-01-03
 4     1 A        2019-01-04 2019-01-04 2019-01-05  # A restarts from 2019-01-04
 5     1 A        2019-01-05 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
 6     2 C        2019-01-06 2019-01-06 2019-01-07
 7     2 C        2019-01-07 2019-01-06 2019-01-07  # C stops at 2019-01-07
 8     2 A        2019-01-08 2019-01-08 2019-01-08  # A stops at 2019-01-08
 9     2 C        2019-01-09 2019-01-09 2019-01-09  # C restarts at 2019-01-09
10     2 A        2019-01-10 2019-01-10 2019-01-10  # A restarts at 2019-01-10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using only `dplyr` where the 'grp' is created by comparing adjacent elements of 'provider', take the cumulative sum of the logical vector and find the `min` and `max` of 'date' after grouping by 'site', 'provider' and 'grp'

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   group_by(site, provider, 
      grp = cumsum(provider != lag(provider, default = first(provider))))  %>% 
   mutate(start = min(date), end = max(date)) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
# A tibble: 10 x 5
#    site provider date       start      end       
#   <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <date>     <date>    
# 1     1 A        2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01
# 2     1 B        2019-01-02 2019-01-02 2019-01-02
3 3     1 C        2019-01-03 2019-01-03 2019-01-03
# 4     1 A        2019-01-04 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
# 5     1 A        2019-01-05 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
# 6     2 C        2019-01-06 2019-01-06 2019-01-07
# 7     2 C        2019-01-07 2019-01-06 2019-01-07
# 8     2 A        2019-01-08 2019-01-08 2019-01-08
# 9     2 C        2019-01-09 2019-01-09 2019-01-09
#10     2 A        2019-01-10 2019-01-10 2019-01-10
```

Comment: Cheers @akrun, this version is neat and works on my larger dataset. I like that it's a pure `dplyr` and appreciate the explanation of how it produces the output.

Comment: @SorenK  Thanks, I just wanted to provide the solution without any additional dependencies.  It may be easier to have lots of packages, but on a production environment, every additional package maintenance is its own headache (with versions and related things)

Answer (score 1):

Use `data.table::rleid` to create an additional group

```
library(dplyr)

x %>%
  group_by(site, provider, group = data.table::rleid(provider)) %>%
  mutate(start = min(date), end = max(date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

 # A tibble: 10 x 5
#    site provider date       start      end       
#   <dbl> <chr>    <date>     <date>     <date>    
# 1     1 A        2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-01
# 2     1 B        2019-01-02 2019-01-02 2019-01-02
# 3     1 C        2019-01-03 2019-01-03 2019-01-03
# 4     1 A        2019-01-04 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
# 5     1 A        2019-01-05 2019-01-04 2019-01-05
# 6     2 C        2019-01-06 2019-01-06 2019-01-07
# 7     2 C        2019-01-07 2019-01-06 2019-01-07
# 8     2 A        2019-01-08 2019-01-08 2019-01-08
# 9     2 C        2019-01-09 2019-01-09 2019-01-09
#10     2 A        2019-01-10 2019-01-10 2019-01-10
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak, while this works perfectly in this sample dataset, for some reason it does not work in my larger dataset (10 years, 55 different sites, 3 different providers). Instead, when I use your code in my dataset, I only get the first `provider` for the entire period per `site` (I tried leaving the `group` column, and true enough, there is only one run length group ID per `site`). Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: @SorenK Are they arranged properly? Try to `arrange` them first `x %>%
  arrange(site, date) %>%
  group_by(site, group = data.table::rleid(provider)) %>%
  mutate(start = min(date), end = max(date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)
`

Comment: yes I tried this, and still it only gives a `start` and `end` date for the first `provider` at the `site`. I've had a look around stackoverflow to see if alternatives to rleid could be used (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507868/is-there-a-dplyr-equivalent-to-data-tablerleid)) but haven't found a working solution.

Comment: @SorenK I don't think it should make a difference but try `x %>%
  group_by(site, provider, group = data.table::rleid(provider)) %>%
  mutate(start = min(date), end = max(date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)`

Comment: That did it! Adding in `provider` to the `group_by` pipe sorted out the code neatly. thank you, that's really helpful.

Comment: Now, I am confused as to in which case `provider` and `rleid(provider)` differ. :D Anyway, I am glad you could figure this out in the end. :)