# Finding the right package in R for cluster analysis

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to find a package in R where I can find clusters that exceed a given threshold in a dataset.

What I want to know is the the cluster duration/size and the individual values of each cluster.

For example (a simple one):

I have a vector of data,

10  8  6 14 14  7 14  5 11 12  8 11 11 16 20  6  8  8  6 15

The clusters that are larger than **9** are defined in bold,

**10**  8  6 **14 14**  7 **14**  5 **11 12**  8 **11 11 16 20**  6  8  8  6 **15**

So here the cluster sizes in order are,

1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1

What I want R to do is return the clusters in separate ordered vectors, e.g.

```
[1] 10
[2] 14 14
[3] 14
[4] 11 12
[5] 11 11 16 20
[6] 15
```

Is there such a package or also a piece of code with if statements for example would also help.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.table::rleid` function works well for this:

```r
Filter(function(a) a[1] > 9, split(vec, data.table::rleid(vec > 9)))
# $`1`
# [1] 10
# $`3`
# [1] 14 14
# $`5`
# [1] 14
# $`7`
# [1] 11 12
# $`9`
# [1] 11 11 16 20
# $`11`
# [1] 15
```

If you'd prefer to not load the `data.table` package just for that, then a base-R approach from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509966:

```r
myrleid <- function(x) {
  rl <- rle(x)$lengths
  rep(seq_along(rl), times = rl)
}
Filter(function(a) a[1] > 9, split(vec, myrleid(vec > 9)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I was looking for.