# Is there a simple way to separate a vector of repeating values in R by the chunks of values and get indices?

Tags: r, vector, indices

I have a dataframe of transect data, such that for each transect, there are species codes and for each species, there is a count associated. I'm trying to calculate a proportion of transects that ID a particular species by separating the data frame into each transect. How can I take a vector of repeating chunks of numbers, separate it by chunks of same values, and get the indices?

Example:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1)
y <- c(3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3)
Transects <- rep(x, y)
```

I want it to output chunks like these

```
c(1, 1, 1)
c(2, 2)
c(1, 1, 1)
c(2, 2, 2)
c(3, 3)
c(1, 1, 1)
```

or more importantly, the associated indices, which would give me

```
c(1, 2, 3)
c(4, 5)
c(6, 7, 8)
c(9, 10, 11)
c(12, 13)
c(14, 15, 16)
```

I don't even know what functions to try, because I don't know what indices to separate the vector at, nor can I separate by simple value because there are chunks of the same values and I don't want those mixed together since they're different transects. Any help is appreciated, I wouldn't even know how to go about building a function that could do this.

Comment: `rleid` from `data.table` will be useful: `split(Transects, data.table::rleid(Transects))`. Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507868/is-there-a-dplyr-equivalent-to-data-tablerleid

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
split(Transects, with(rle(Transects), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))

$`1`
[1] 1 1 1

$`2`
[1] 2 2

$`3`
[1] 1 1 1

$`4`
[1] 2 2 2

$`5`
[1] 3 3

$`6`
[1] 1 1 1
```

Or if interested in indices:

```
split(seq_along(Transects), with(rle(Transects), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))

$`1`
[1] 1 2 3

$`2`
[1] 4 5

$`3`
[1] 6 7 8

$`4`
[1]  9 10 11

$`5`
[1] 12 13

$`6`
[1] 14 15 16
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
split(Transects, cumsum(c(0, diff(Transects)) != 0))
```

Comment: @Andrew I'm not sure whether we should consider the x and y vectors. I think they were used just to create the Transects vector.

Comment: Thank you so much, the second one that returns indices is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I tried to upvote your response, but I don't have enough reputation for it to change the public score yet, sorry.

Comment: Don't worry about that, I'm glad it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map2` function from `purrr` package:

purrr::map2(x, y, rep)

Comment: That breaks up the chunks the way I want, but doesn't get me the indices for them so that I can manipulate the counts of individual transects.