# Numbering a Vector that Has Repeats Up Until a New Element

Tags: r, tidyverse

If I have a vector such as :

```
c("A","A","B","B","A","C","C","C","D","A","B","C")
```

And I'm interested in numbering it, based upon repeats upon until they hit a new element. Such as:

```
1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8
```

How can I go about this? So far, I wrote this:

```
x <- map(seq_along(u), ~str_locate_all(str_flatten(u), u[[.x]]))
```

Comment: `rleid` or `rle`

Comment: Is there any tidyverse equivalent of that? Not that there's anything wrong with data.table. :P

Comment: Yes, it would be `cumsum(v1 != lag(v1, default = first(v1))) + 1`

Comment: I thought cumsum() is Base R?

Comment: Yes, but `lag` is from `dplyr`

Comment: Ah, you're right! Appreciate the help - I'll stick to rleid haha

Comment: Related post: [Is there a dplyr equivalent to data.table::rleid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33507868/680068)