# Labelling rows according to how many times the group appeared in previous rows

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, vectorization

Suppose I have the following `data.frame` object:

```r
df = data.frame(id=(1:25),
                col1=c('a','a','a',
                       'b','b','b',
                       'c','c','c',
                       'd','d',
                       'b','b','b',
                       'e',
                       'c','c','c',
                       'e','e',
                       'a','a','a',
                       'e','e'))
```

[image: snapshot of the input dataframe with groupings for "a" and "e"]

From the snapshot above, you can see that there are two groups of rows that have `col1=="a"`: rows 1 through 3 and rows 21 through 23. Similarly, there are three groups of rows that have `col1=="e"`: row 15, rows 19 through 20 and rows 24 through 25 (and so on and so on with `"b"`, `"c"` and `"d"`).

### Here's my main question

Is it possible to label the rows according to what "chunk" we're currently on? More explicitly: since rows 1 through 3 are the **first** time where we have `col1=="a"`, they should be labelled as 1. Then, rows 21 through 23 should be labelled as 2, because that is the **second** time that we have a set of rows that have `col1=="a"`. Using the same logic, but for `col1=="e"`, we'd label row 15 as 1, rows 19 and 20 as 2 and rows 24 and 25 as 3 (again, so on and so on with `"b"`, `"c"` and `"d"`).

#### Desired output

Here is what the resulting `data.frame` would look like:

```r
df = data.frame(id=(1:25),
                col1=c('a','a','a',
                       'b','b','b',
                       'c','c','c',
                       'd','d',
                       'b','b','b',
                       'e',
                       'c','c','c',
                       'e','e',
                       'a','a','a',
                       'e','e'),
                grup=c(1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,
                       1,1,1,
                       1,1,
                       2,2,2,
                       1,
                       2,2,2,
                       2,2,
                       2,2,2,
                       3,3))
```

[image: snapshot of the desired result]

#### My attempt

I tried implementing a solution using a `for` loop, but that was quite slow (the original data I'm working on has about 500,000 rows), and it just looked a bit sloppy:

```r
my_classifier = function(input_df, ref_column){
  # Keeps a tally of how many times each unique group was "found" before.
  group_counter = list()
  
  # Dealing with the corner case of the first row
  group_counter[[df$col1[1]]] = 1
  output_groups = rep(-1, nrow(input_df))
  output_groups[1] = 1
  
  # The for loop starts at the second row because I've already "dealt" with the
  # first row in the corner cases above
  for(i in 2:nrow(input_df)){
    prev_group = input_df[[ref_column]][i-1]
    this_group = input_df[[ref_column]][i]
    if(is.null(group_counter[[this_group]])){
      this_counter = 0
    }
    else{
      this_counter = group_counter[[this_group]]
    }
    if(prev_group != this_group){
      this_counter = this_counter + 1
    }
    output_groups[i] = this_counter
    group_counter[[this_group]] = this_counter
  }
  
  return(output_groups)
}

df$grup = my_classifier(df,'col1')
```

Is there a quicker/more efficient way to solve this problem? Maybe something that relies on vectorized functions or something?

#### Important notes

Consider that we cannot rely on the number of repetitions of each "block". Sometimes, `col1` will have just one single row of a particular group, while other times the "block" will have several rows where `col1` share the same value. Also consider that we cannot assume any logic in the "order" or the number of times each group shows up.

So, for example, there might be a a stretch of 10 rows where `col1=="z"`, then a stretch of 15 rows where `col1=="x"`, then another single row where `col1=="x"` and then finally a stretch of 100 rows where `col1=="w"`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `data.table::rleid()` twice, like this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,grp:=rleid(col1)][, grp:=rleid(grp), by=col1][order(id)]
```

Output:

```
       id   col1   grp
    <int> <char> <int>
 1:     1      a     1
 2:     2      a     1
 3:     3      a     1
 4:     4      b     1
 5:     5      b     1
 6:     6      b     1
 7:     7      c     1
 8:     8      c     1
 9:     9      c     1
10:    10      d     1
11:    11      d     1
12:    12      b     2
13:    13      b     2
14:    14      b     2
15:    15      e     1
16:    16      c     2
17:    17      c     2
18:    18      c     2
19:    19      e     2
20:    20      e     2
21:    21      a     2
22:    22      a     2
23:    23      a     2
24:    24      e     3
25:    25      e     3
       id   col1   grp
```

Comment: I was just about to post this with `dplyr`, which is:  `df %>% mutate(grp = rleid(col1)) %>%  group_by(col1) %>%  mutate(grp = rleid(grp))`

Comment: Thanks, [@AndrewGB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15293191/andrewgb)! I also really like this shorthand `dplyr` approach!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible base R solution:

```
change <- with(rle(df$col1), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))

cbind(df, grp = with(df, ave(
  change,
  col1,
  FUN = function(x)
    inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x), values <- seq_along(values)))
)))
```

Or another option using a combination of `rle` and `dplyr` using the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509966/15293191):

```
rle_new <- function(x) {
  x <- rle(x)$lengths
  rep(seq_along(x), times=x)
}

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(grp = rle_new(col1)) %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate(grp = rle_new(grp))
```

**Output**

```
   id col1 grp
1   1    a   1
2   2    a   1
3   3    a   1
4   4    b   1
5   5    b   1
6   6    b   1
7   7    c   1
8   8    c   1
9   9    c   1
10 10    d   1
11 11    d   1
12 12    b   2
13 13    b   2
14 14    b   2
15 15    e   1
16 16    c   2
17 17    c   2
18 18    c   2
19 19    e   2
20 20    e   2
21 21    a   2
22 22    a   2
23 23    a   2
24 24    e   3
25 25    e   3
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for the two suggestions! I tried them both and they work, but I had to make a few adjustments. For the solution in base R, I needed to change `change <- with(rle(df$col1), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))`  to `change <- with(rle(as.character(df$col1)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))`. Similarly, in the `dplyr` solution, I needed to change `mutate(grp = rle_new(col1))` with `mutate(grp = rle_new(as.character(col1)))`. If I didn't make those changes, R would throw the following error: `'x' must be a vector of an atomic type`.

Comment: @FelipeD. Awesome! I didn't have that issue with the sample data, but I think that can happen with different encoding sometimes, but converting to character obviously takes care of that.